# How to add doc in elasticsearch without specify the id with python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to add doc in elastic search using python elasticsearch but in the example on the [documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/) i have this code and on this example is specify the id , i dont want to specify the id, I want elastic to generate id for me like this for example AK3286826fds83

```
def addBrandInES():

    doc = {
        'author': 'kimchy',
        'text': 'Elasticsearch: cool. bonsai cool.',
        'timestamp': datetime.now(),
    }

    # res = es.index(index="brands", doc_type='external', id=1, body=doc)
    res = es.index(index="brands", doc_type='external', body=doc) <-- can i do that ??
    print(res['created'])
```

Comment: yes you can. I will auto-generate an id for that doc.

Comment: you can also send it using requests module.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can simply omit the `id` parameter. When the parameter is missing, Elasticsearch will create one for that document. The following snippet is from the elasticsearch-py `index` method:

```
def index(self, index, doc_type, body, id=None, params=None):
        """
        Adds or updates a typed JSON document in a specific index, making it searchable.
        `<http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html>`_

        :arg index: The name of the index
        :arg doc_type: The type of the document
        :arg body: The document
        :arg id: Document ID
        :arg op_type: Explicit operation type, default 'index', valid choices
            are: 'index', 'create'
        :arg parent: ID of the parent document
        :arg pipeline: The pipeline id to preprocess incoming documents with
        :arg refresh: If `true` then refresh the affected shards to make this
            operation visible to search, if `wait_for` then wait for a refresh
            to make this operation visible to search, if `false` (the default)
            then do nothing with refreshes., valid choices are: u'true',
            u'false', u'wait_for'
        :arg routing: Specific routing value
        :arg timeout: Explicit operation timeout
        :arg timestamp: Explicit timestamp for the document
        :arg ttl: Expiration time for the document
        :arg version: Explicit version number for concurrency control
        :arg version_type: Specific version type, valid choices are: 'internal',
            'external', 'external_gte', 'force'
        :arg wait_for_active_shards: Sets the number of shard copies that must
            be active before proceeding with the index operation. Defaults to 1,
            meaning the primary shard only. Set to `all` for all shard copies,
            otherwise set to any non-negative value less than or equal to the
            total number of copies for the shard (number of replicas + 1)
        """
        for param in (index, doc_type, body):
            if param in SKIP_IN_PATH:
                raise ValueError("Empty value passed for a required argument.")
        return self.transport.perform_request('POST' if id in SKIP_IN_PATH else 'PUT',
            _make_path(index, doc_type, id), params=params, body=body)
```

Note the second to the last line: the `SKIP_IN_PATH` is defined as:

```
SKIP_IN_PATH = (None, '', b'', [], ())
```

So if `id` is missing, HTTP 'POST' will be used, which is creating a new object, otherwise 'PUT' will be used, which is to update an existing document.

There is another API named `create()`, which requires the `id` to be set. This API is used specifically to create a document with a specified id.

Comment: es.index() is legit

Answer (score -2):

```py
res = es.index(index="brands", doc_type='external', body=doc , id=<your id>)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: The question asks not to specify the id